# Extract value form stack raster by using SpatialDataPoint in R

Tags: r, spatial

I have a stake in raster data of Landsat and I want to extract the values of them by employing SpatialPointData in R and then plot the extracted values with the associated variables in SpatialPointData and finally, I want to exported the extracted data along with the variable in the attribute of the spatial point object. I have used extract function to do so but the problem is that after extracting I got several errors every time and sometimes it works but it gives me only a data frame as a matrix which I cant match them with observation point.

My scripts

```
      #raster
      lsat <- stack(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6_1,b6_2,b7)
      #SpatialPoint
      soil_sp=SpatialPoints(cbind(soil.clean2$x,soil.clean2$y))
```

Extrcat the value from stack layer

```
     soil_sp$ref<- extract(lsat2, soil_sp)
```

plot the extrced value and observed value in point data for each band

```
     plot( soil_sp$ref ~., data=soil_sp)
```

Finally, I want to export the extracted value along with variable in point data in a single data frame or SpatialPointsDataFrame.

Comment: Since this code could not run on our machines without those b-objects, we need to ask what problems you are encountering? Saying you got errors is not particularly specific. Have you tried to pare down this data to a simple example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use SpatialPointDataFrame to extract the value of stack raster and then write the result into a CSV file or whatever you would like.

implementation:
Crerate SpatialPointDataFram out of SpatialPointData

```
  soil_spdf=SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = soil_sp,data = soil.clean2, 
  proj4string = soil_crs)
```

Extrcat the values.

```
soil_spdf$ref <- extract(lsat2 , soil_spdf)
```

write the data in CSV file in the desired directory on your PC.

```
write.csv(x =soil_spdf,file ="C:/lsat2.csv")
```